# Checking for case sensitivity within .Any in NHibernate

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

My issue started off trying to find a case sensitive comparison to use with NHibernate.

```
public List<MessageLog> GetLogsByFileAndEventName (string fileName, string eventName, DateTime? after,
     DateTime? before)
  {
     var query = m_session.QueryOver<Log> ()
        .Where (x => x.CreatedOn >= after && x.CreatedOn <= before);

     if (fileName != null)
        (2) query = query.Where (x => x.FileName.Equals (fileName));
     if (eventName != null)
        (3) query = query.Where (x => x.LogRecords.Any (y => y.Event.Name.Equals (eventName)));

     return query.List<Log>().ToList();
  }
```

I have now replaced line 2 with

```
query = query.Where (Expression.Sql (" FileName = ? COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS", fileName, NHibernateUtil.String));
```

which yields a case sensitive comparison. I'm trying to use similar behavior when comparing event names(line 3), however this causes a mismatch with the arguments.

Edit: I've tried

```
query = query.Where (x => x.Records.Any(Expression.Sql (" SomeEvent.Name = ? COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS", eventName, NHibernateUtil.String)));
```

This results in `"Argument type 'Nhibernate.Criterion.AbstractCriterion' is not assignable to parameter type 'System.Func<projectname.Dir.Nhibernate.Logs.LogRecord, bool>'`

I've tried a couple other ways with linq(I'm fairly new to it) that don't yield the results that I want prior to case comparison.

**My Question:**

What would be the best way to check for case sensitivity on event name in line 3?

Comment: Your third linq example looks wrong. What do you expect from `.Where(...) != null`? Semantically, it should always yields true. I guess it should be `.Any(...)` instead.

Comment: And may you include what you have tried for your line 3? Something like  `query.Where (x => x.Records.Any(Expression.Sql(" SomeEvent.Name = ? COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS", eventName, NHibernateUtil.String)));`?

Comment: Thanks for the replies! When I copied line 3, I accidentally copied one of the expressions I had been trying with the Expression.Sql instead of the original .Any().

Comment: I guess you get an exception with your tried code, you should include its details (at least complete exception message and inner exception messages if any). There is also a mismatch between your third linq and your tried code : you compare to `eventName` in 3., to `fileName` in your tried code. By the way, how are declared and initialized those variables? Add some more lines in your code excerpts to show it. And how are declared `SomeEvent.Name` and `FileName` properties? Maybe there is something there (or in their mappings).

Comment: The mismatch is because I used an alternate way to finish writing the code that is case *insensitive*. I've updated the post with the full code body for the method. Declarations for the eventname and filename will be added when I have time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the [QueryOver](http://nhibernate.info/blog/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.html) API, which is not a linq API. It can use lambda expression as linq, but it is not linq.

I was believing you were having an exception, but you have a compilation error instead. You cannot combine NHibernate criterion (`Expression.Sql` yields a criterion) with linq methods (`Any` is a linq method, whereas in your code `query.Where` is a QueryOver method).

If you want to use linq, you should use linq-to-nhibernate instead.

```
using NHibernate.Linq;
...
var query = m_session.Query<Log>();
```

As far as I know, specifying collation is not supported in linq-to-nibernate. But you may extend it, as shown for [another need here](/a/21060461/1178314) or [here](/a/35492489/1178314).

If you want to use QueryOver, using linq subqueries (the Any) does not look to me as the way subqueries are supposed to be expressed with [QueryOver](http://nhibernate.info/blog/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.html). I am not familiar with QueryOver, you should sort out how to express your additional restriction from its documentation. Or ask a new question about it.